# Dont show digits after decimal using angular pipe

Tags: angular

I have a progress bar with whose progress could range from 0.1 to 99.999

I dont want to use math.round in the ts file coz it will mess up the logic. I only want to show it without decimal like 44.983 should be 44

```
<div>
{{percentage}}
</div>
```

Comment: use `number ` pipe with `digitsInfo = 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Number pipe` with `digitsInfo = 0`

```
{{ num | number:'1.0-0' }}
```

Working demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jitvhs)

Comment: it rounds off so i think math.trunc would be better solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can achieve this by using **Angular pipe.**

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({name: 'round'})
export class RoundPipe {
  transform (input:number) {
    return Math.floor(input);
  }
}

<div>{{percentage | round}}</div>
```